# show navigation buttons only on mouse over

Tags: css, pagination, slideshow, react-swiper

I'm tring to do that with CSS but it isn't working. I've tried using:

```
.swiper-button-prev {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-button-prev:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

but it doesn't effect at all. if I do add some rule like `background-color: yellow` it does affect the element so the CSS is applied. What am I missing? here's the [`full`](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-react-forked-7m2fw9?file=/src/styles.css) thing

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This element seems to have a `display: flex` with a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), which will override the `display: none` in posted example. Also `:hover` will not work if display is turned off for the element.

Try use [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) to hide the element, perhaps also consider give it a lower opacity such as `opacity: 0.2` when not hovered, so that the user can still know that the button exists.

Forked project: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-react-forked-13zs4g?file=/src/styles.css)

Example:

```
.swiper-button-prev {
  opacity: 0;
}

.swiper-button-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```